# Suppressing syntax error at compile time

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm wondering if it is possible to suppress a syntax error at compile time in Python.

My office currently runs on 2.4, although we're trying to move everyone to 2.7 and then 3.x, it is taking some time. As a result we have both a 2.4 and 2.7 interpreter on all our servers.

Considering the size of some of the files we have to process, running a file in 2.7 is usually optimal, but the `python` command defaults to 2.4 and most people aren't aware of, or simply won't use, `python27`.

As a result I'm making a small header to add to some Python scripts which will rerun the scripts in 2.7 if it detects it is in anything lower:

```
if sys.version_info[0] == 2 and sys.version_info[1] < 7:
    print "This file is best run in python 2.7 for performance purposes."
    print
    print "Running in 2.7 now..."
    subprocess.call('python27', 'python_process.py', sys.argv[1])
```

I haven't had a chance to test this yet as when I run the file in 2.4 I immediately get a syntax error:

```
File "x:\phlib\pyprg\replace_double_with_single_quotes.py", line 12
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as to_clean, \
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is the whole line it errors on:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as to_clean, \
     open(sys.argv[1]+'.clean', 'wb') as cleaned:
```

If I run the file in just 2.7, it works fine.

This is obviously because 2.4 doesn't understand the `with` statement, and while I could simply remove the with and use file.open()/file.close(), we would like to take advantage of the new functions and libraries in 2.7 prior to moving to 3.x.

So I would like to know if it is possible to suppress this `SyntaxError` to allow the program to run. And if it is, how?

Comment: give code before `with` statment.

Comment: Why don't you write your version compatibility code prior to the syntaxerror?

Comment: @Lafada: what difference would that make?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, `with` is 12th line in code file. There might be error in above 11 line.

Comment: You cannot control compile-time issues *from the same file*, no. Your top-level scripts *have* to be Python 2.4 compatible for your switch to work. Move everything out of the main script into a module, for example.

Comment: @Lafada: It **doesn't matter**. The Python interpreter operates in two stages: loading the file (which compiles it) and running it. If there is a syntax error when loading, you cannot run the code. It doesn't matter what the other lines are, those lines posted cause a syntax error on Python 2.4.

Comment: @Lafada: the problem then, is that the OP is trying to work around the issue with Python code *in the same file*. In Python 2.7 the file will run, in Python 2.4 it won't compile so their compatibility switch will never run either.

Comment: @MartijnPieters totally agree.

Comment: @Lafada: besides, there is no (Python 2.4) syntax error in the lines above line 12, because the code posted is indeed a syntax error in Python 2.4 and that is the first error the compiler found.

Comment: the version specific code starts at line 2, with comes as an else statement to the version specific if

Comment: Was hoping there would be a way to supress errors pre compiling in the script but knew it was a longshot! I'll move it to a modular base

Comment: Technically you could do it but you would have to some code using exec after checking  `if "with" in keywords.list`

Comment: @padraiccunningham I would have to put the whole indented `with` block into `exec` in that case wouldn't I?

Comment: To open and read you just need   `exec("""with open('foo.txt') as f:lines=f.read()""")` then you can use lines outside that. You could write the code as is just in strings and exec it or just the parts you are using with

Comment: @padraicCunningham whilst true for small files, the file we're currently talking about is 15GB, and isn't the largest file I've seen. That would kill the servers on a daily basis.

Comment: I thought it was just the header you were having trouble with

Comment: Sorry, when I said header, I meant I'm adding a header to the python scripts to run them in 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot control compile-time issues *from the same file*, no. Your top-level scripts *have* to be Python 2.4 compatible for your switch to work. Move everything out of the main script into a module, for example.

Your other option is to update all those servers to replace `python` with a wrapper script that does the switching for you. That can be done with a `python` command in a place listed earlier in `PATH`, or with a shell alias.

Comment: Annoying thing is that our sys-admins are moving slow on installing the last py27 module we need so we can't just force python to == python2.7. Sounds like you're right on the module front, although I hoped to avoid splitting up the script, it will make things more confusing for the users. Thanks